# Is there a quicker way to check is a LDAP user is in a LDAP Group? This is slow as it checks each one each time?

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, adldap

Using adldap-laravel and Laravel 5.8.

I'm getting permissions based on LDAP groups. I can check if a user is part of a group using: `$user->ldap->inGroup('Accounts');` (that returns a bool)

However that method also accepts an `array`, but seems to be an "AND" search, rather than "ANY".

So I've written this:

```
/**
     * LDAP helper, to see if the user is in an AD group.
     * Iterate through and break when a match is found.
     *
     * @param mixed $input
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isInGroup($input)
    {
        if (is_string($input)) {
            $input[] = $input;
        }

        foreach ($input as $group)
            if ($this->ldap->inGroup($group)) {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Implemented like this: 
`$user->isInGroup(['Accounts', 'Sales', 'Marketing']);`

However it takes a long time to check.

Does anyone know of an improved way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes can do it via query builder of Adldap.

```
     /**
     * LDAP helper, to see if the user is in an AD group.
     * Iterate through and break when a match is found.
     *
     * @param mixed $input
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isInGroup($input){

        if (is_string($input)) {
            $input[] = $input;
        }

        $counter = 0;
        $groupQuery = $this->ldap->search()->groups();
        foreach ($input as $group) {
            if ($counter == 0) {
                $groupQuery->where('samaccountname', '=', $group);
            } else {
                $groupQuery->orWhere('samaccountname', '=', $group);
            }
$counter++;
        }

        return $groupQuery->get()->count();
     }
```

This **samaccountname** may be different field name for your LDAP provider. I couldn't tested it if has any syntax or method name error anyway you will find this same methods from your `Adldap Provider class`. The algorithm/process is same.